# How to enable GPU switching

Tags: laptop, amd-graphics, acer

How do I enable VGA switcheroo? Is there any way I can do it with a GUI? I am setting it up for someone who is not at all CLI friendly. See the kernel module switcheroo if you don't know it yet.

It's for an [Acer Aspire 5820TG-6406](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/ID/content/support-product/2113;-;).

Answer (score 0):

## [Ubuntu Control Center](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/ubuntu-control-center-061-released.html)

[image]

[image]

> Ubuntu Control Center (UCC) is an unofficial application inspired by
> Mandriva Control Center, designed to bring simplicity and a less
> cluttered interface (because a lot of applications add themselves to
> the GNOME Control Center automatically) to manage the Ubuntu system
> settings for the simple user.
>
> Besides being an application you can use to launch various system
> settings, UCC also lets you switch between low and high performance
> graphics cards (if you have a netbook with 2 GPUs)

Download Link : [32-Bit](http://www.easy-share.com/1915871724/ucc061_i386.deb) , [64-Bit](http://www.easy-share.com/1915871596/ucc061_amd64.deb)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be available anymore. None of the downloads links I can find work.